# Audio Sounds Like It's Skipping in Lightworks

Tags: audio, audio-quality, lightworks

This is my first time using Lightworks.

I have some video I recorded of some gameplay that I am trying to edit. While the audio itself sounds fine in other programs, every time I play it in Lightsworks it almost sounds like it is skipping but I'm pretty sure it is in sync.

What is odd is that when I tried to mute the audio I could still hear the noise.  I tried then to mute the audio and replace it with a copy of it and it still won't work.  Does anyone have any advice?

- audio copy is in .wav and video in .avi
- was recorded using Bandicam

Answer (score 2):

**Get a better computer.** The fact that the audio sounds fine in other apps means it was recorded fine, and the file represents the audio correctly. When you open it in your editor though, that's a much more complex operation than simply *playing* the video in an optimized player. So, I think this is a performance issue. I've had this problem myself with cheaper computers, and back when I switched to HD, I had to buy a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a different file type, like an MP3. I'd use CloudConvert. I think it could be an issue with audio support, but I'm not sure. I had a problem with the audio appearing choppy. I converted it to an MP3, and it worked fine. I know this was made seven years ago but, I hope this helps anyone with a similar issue!